# Align list items under input box with flexbox

Tags: css

Im trying to align the ul lis under an input box and send the span element to the right of the input box

I read other threads and how to send the span to the left with justify-content: space-between; but that doesn't want to work too. Also tried to add margin to the list to push the text around but it doesn't feel right not to mention that I still cant figure out how to stick the delete span to the right. Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h0w6yp1x/

```
.list { justify-content: space-between;}
.list li { justify-content: space-between;}
```

Comment: You width under `.list` class is 100%, why don't you reduce it to maybe 60%, or just remove `width:100%` and then `justify-content` should work, you shouldn't do both.

Comment: i was experimenting with the width . leaving it to just justify-content doesnt work aswell

Comment: @Frozendawn Doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Define a wrapper `div` between `li` tags. And make it `flexbox`, then **justify content of this wrapper div**.

Like this:

```
   <li>
     <div class="li-wrapper"> Random Text1 <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div>
   </li>
```

---

Working code is below:

```js
const DOM = {
  input: document.querySelector('.user-input'),
  list: document.querySelector('.list'),
  btnAdd: document.querySelector('.btn-add'),
  btnDelete: document.querySelector('.btn-remove')
}

let addItem = function() {
  if (DOM.input.value === '') {
    return;
  } else {
    const html = `<li> <div class="li-wrapper">${DOM.input.value} <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div> </li>`;
    DOM.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    DOM.input.value = '';
  }

};

let removeItem = function(element) {

  element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
}

DOM.btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addItem();
});

DOM.list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let element = e.target;
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("span.btn-remove")) {
    removeItem(element);

  }


})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  background: #d53369;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #cbad6d, #d53369);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #cbad6d, #d53369);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.user-inerface {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.user-input {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.btn-add {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.list {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #9400D3;
}

.li-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list li:nth-child(2n+2) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.list li:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <div class="user-interface">
      <input type="text" class="user-input" placeholder="New todo">
      <button class="btn-add">Add</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="list">

      <li>
        <div class="li-wrapper"> Random Text1 <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="li-wrapper"> Random Text1 <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div>
      </li>
       <li>
        <div class="li-wrapper"> Random Text1 <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div>
      </li>
       <li>
        <div class="li-wrapper"> Random Text1 <span class="btn-remove">delete</span></div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the .list li selector to have display: flex then that appears to cause the items in the list box to show the text on one side and the delete on the other.